# knnMatch in OpenCV version 2.4.10

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Anyone know how to call knnMatch in version 2.4.10?

I used it in this way, but it doesn't work and met errors. Anyone know how to use it?

```
std::vector< DMatch > matches;  
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true); 
Mat mask;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 2, mask, false);  // Find two nearest matches
```

The error is:  **no instance of overloaded function "cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch" matches the argument list**

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a toy example that can run successfully on 2.4.10. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the declaration of matches :

```
    vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;
```